# parse push notifications not working ios

Tags: ios, push-notification

I installed Parse sdk on my iphone app. This is for xcode 4.5.
I get the modal request to enable push notifications.
The subscription is successful. The token shows up on the parse web app. 
Says 1 user subscribed. 
But I dont get a notification from the web app.

I just cant understand what to do here.

All the provisioning madness should be correct. 
Was done for development.

I am using the below code to listen for the notifications.

But never gets fired. What am i doing wrong here???

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
NSLog(@"received push %@", userInfo);
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: Is your problem on parsing notification info or not getting the notification on the device? I recommend to take a look at Apple documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your app's push notification page in the Parse dashboard, which should be at `https://www.parse.com/apps/(your app)/push_notifications`.  If the push notification doesn't appear there, then your notification didn't get sent, and the problem is on the web app's side.
2. Try sending the push notification while your app isn't running.  If you get the notification, then it's something in your app.  If you don't get the notification, then you must have set up the push notification incorrectly somewhere.

Also, Parse has a pretty detailed [tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications).

Comment: i am getting the notification on the parse app. I cant see what can be wrong about the setup. The device is there and subscribed to. Everything looks fine. It just doesnt fire the receive function.

Comment: Guys, I have followed the tutorial from the Parse.com itself and 3 to 4 times created the certificates and provisioning profile. but I am not able to test in Adhoc mode. Only debug mode works.

Comment: Thanks @MoeezAkram . I tried my hand first on adhoc mode and it didn't work. After reading your comment I tried in debug mode and it worked !